# Make visibility "sticky" on click, using css styling of SVG components

Tags: css, svg, hover

I want to construct an SVG image containing components which reveal additional content on mouse-over.

I've managed this using css to set the `visibility` style to visible for a target object, based on mouseover of a sibling trigger object.

What I'd now like to do is fix the visibility attribute on click - such that clicking elsewhere resets the visibility back to hidden. If I can get that to work, then I'd be able to reveal content on click for multiple elements, without resorting to any javascript.

I have considered recoding this using form objects like radio buttons etc, but would prefer the layout flexibility provided by raw SVG, since I want to be able to position the active elements as precisely as possible.

The below reveals a callout-type box, but does so only on mouseover. Clicking to set the focus to the trigger circle does have the effect of restyling the callout box, but I want the visibility to remain 'sticky' so that once the mouse stops hovering, it remains visible. Currently, on moving the mouse away from the circle, the callout box disappears.

```html
<svg width="450" height="300">
    <style>
    #text_box_test{
    fill:#FFAAAA;
    }
    
    #hover_thing:hover ~ #text_box_test {
    visibility:visible;
    }
    
    #hover_thing:active ~#text_box_test {
    visibility:visible;
    fill:#AAFFAA;
    }
    
    div.white {
    #background-color:#FFFFFF;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    }
    
    a:focus ~ #text_box_test {
    fill: #77BBFF;
    fill-opacity: 1.0;
    outline: none;
    visibility:visible;
}
    </style>
    <g>
    <a id="hover_thing" xlink:href="#" tabindex="1">
    <circle id="hover_thing" cx="15" cy="150" r="10" stroke="black" stroke-width="3" fill="red" data-Name="shape 1" data-tabindex="0"/>
    </a>
            
            <g id="text_box_test" visibility="hidden">
            <path 
            stroke-width="3" 
            stroke="black"
            stroke-linejoin="miter"
            fill-opacity="0.85"
                  d="M 20 150 
                     l 40 -15
                     l 0 -75
                     a 10 10 0 0 1 10 -10
                     l 250 0
                     a 10 10 0 0 1 10 10
                     l 0 150
                     a 10 10 0 0 1 -10 10
                     l -250 0
                     a 10 10 0 0 1 -10 -10
                     l 0 -45 z"/>
            <foreignObject x="70" y="60" width="250px" height="150px">
            <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" class="white">
                <h1 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Header Shmeader</h1>
                <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Text goes here - If more text goes over a thing, then it wraps around. <br> <br> Any more and it may overflow. </p>
                <p xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Freddie was a little fish, his skin was nice and shiny, and everywhere that Freddie went, he tried to not get grimy. </p>
            </div>
            </foreignObject>
        </g>


        </g>
            </g>
    </svg>
```

N.B. Original code edited to reflect information provided in the answer.

Comment: Also, any pointers on how to demonstrate the code above "live" most welcome, as it stands you'd need to wrap the above in an html document and launch it in a browser (so far, tested in Chrome and Safari with the results outlined above)

Comment: [later] Aha! Just discovered "Code Snippets"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like "visible is spelled wrong in your `a:focus ~ #text_box_test` rule (You may need to add `tabindex="1"` to your `<a>` if your focus isn't working).

If you want hover AND click to happen for multiple elements, your best option would be to use javascript. Though it could be done using checkboxes, if you're willing to move away from SVG, as demonstrated here:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VNqyQY?editors=1100

Comment: OK that's interesting - I couldn't quite get the sticky behaviour from directly removing the `:hover` stylings, but will experiment with that further. The other thing I'm getting a feel for is trying to cross the svg barrier between having a collection of checkboxes or radio buttons described within a form, and then referenced indirectly by `label` objects within the SVG. I can't seem to get the two domains to talk to each other though.

Comment: You have "visible" spelled wrong in your `a:focus ~ #text_box_test` rule. Changing that should fix the sticky part!

Comment: Haha! Oh dear, very embarrassing! But - overall, happy to have solved the problem - thankyou for your close inspection - yes, it seems to do exactly what I'd hoped. Interestingly however, this works in Chrome, but not in Safari. I get different behaviors between the two. To be expected I guess.

Comment: It happens to the best of us! Did you try adding `tabindex="1"` to the `<a>`? It seems to work for me in Safari when `tabindex` is defined.

Comment: Yes, perfect - this opens up a whole load of UX possibilities, thank you very much!

Comment: Awesome! Remember, though, that `:focus` only applies to one element at a time. If you want to be able to select multiple elements at the same time, check out the Pen in the answer for how to execute using checkboxes. Cheers!